# How to write an algorithm in java to evaluate an arithmetic expression with brackets

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation

I understand how to write java algorithm without brackets.

1. Create two stacks: an operand stack and an operator stack.
2. As we read an expression, keep adding the operator in one and operand in other.
3. Operator with lower precedence cannot be stored on operator with higher precedence. In that case we pop that operator and apply to top operands from Operand stack and keep
   the result in place.

But if it involves brackets like `[] or {} or ()`. What would be the logic to evaluate the expression? eg

```
([12*3] + (8/2)) + (5+5)/(4*2)-3+(7-3)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes..without bracket I have tried. With bracket logic I need to understand..Checked couple of old blogs but could not figure out how that works.

Comment: "The algorithm in detail" and "Detailed example" on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) describes how parentheses are handled.

Comment: If you understand the shunting-yard algorithm with parenthesis it should be trivial to extend it to more than one kind of parenthesis. Just do *exactly* the same thing you do for parenthesis just with brackets.

Comment: must read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: The word is 'algorithm', not 'algo'. It's derived from the name of a famous mathematician. Don't abbreviate it.

Answer (score 3):

You're describing a strange variation on Dijkstra's [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).  Dijkstra's version has been the norm for the last 50 years, and it handles grouped operations (parentheses, brackets, *etc.*) just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to evaluate arithmetic expressions is to develop or lookup a grammar for arithmetic expressions, see here http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeProgLang/Grammar/Arith-Exp/ for example and then code a "recursive descent parser". Those programms have a structure very close to the grammar. Once you see one you will appreciate this approach.